# Return value of a select statement that has no rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

If I did the following statement:

```
set @ParentMemberID = (select MemberID from tblMembers where ThirdPartyReference like @Branch_ThirdPartyReference)
```

And there was no result. What would the value of @ParentMemberID be?

Thanks

Comment: Try and find out....  It is `NULL`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply check the value yourself by using the `SELECT` keyword:

```
 set @ParentMemberID = (select MemberID from tblMembers where ThirdPartyReference like @Branch_ThirdPartyReference)

 --This will show you the value of @ParentMemberID 
 SELECT @ParentMemberID
```

Answer (score 2):

A simplified test

```
declare @I int
set @I = 0
set @I = (select 1 where 0 = 1)
select @I
```

Result:

```
NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be below is the query what you're looking for, please use it,

```
SET @ParentMemberID = ISNULL((SELECT MemberID FROM tblMembers 
          WHERE ThirdPartyReference LIKE @Branch_ThirdPartyReference), 0)

SELECT @ParentMemberID
```

## EDIT:

If you don't need to check `NULL` then below query will suite perfectly:

```
SET @ParentMemberID = (SELECT MemberID FROM tblMembers 
          WHERE ThirdPartyReference LIKE @Branch_ThirdPartyReference)

SELECT @ParentMemberID
```